# how to restrict user from submitting contact form again and again without session from its IP address in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, ip

I want to restrict user from its IP address from submitting contact form again and again. How to do that in asp.net MVC? Can anybody help me? I know how to retrieve IP of user but I don't know how to use it to restrict user from submitting the form again

**My controller code**

```
string IP = String.Empty;

System.Web.HttpContext current = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
string IPAddress = current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(IPAddress))
{
    string[] valAddress = IPAddress.Split('.');
    if(valAddress.Length != 0)
    {
        IP = valAddress[0];
    }
}

IP = current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? what if you have three people connected at the same wifi? only one can submit?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do that. The important question is, what is your job spec?

If you develop public website, such as stackoverflow or facebook etc, you should consider implement validation on both client and back-end side. If you develop an intranet based web application, client side verification would be enough.

If your form is simple contact form kind of form, you should use Google ReCaptcha to prevent automated codes, robots, to prevent bombing your database or your email.

https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/v3beta.html

Here is how I achieve to prevent users send multiple.

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(YourViewModel model)
        {
            #region backend validation

            if (
                !GoogleReCAPTCHAHelper.Check(Request["g-recaptcha-response"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GoogleReCAPTCHASecret"]))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "You have to confirm that you are not robot!");
                return View(model);
            }

            if ((from file in model.Files where file != null select file.FileName.Split('.')).Any(arr => arr[arr.Length - 1].ToLower() != "pdf"))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "We only accept PDF files!");
                return View(model);
            }
            if (model.Files.Count() > 2)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                    "You have exceeded maximum file upload size. You can upload maximum 2 PDF file!");
                return View(model);
            }

            //// this stops the applicant sending the application multiple times within 5 minutes of a submition
            DateTime? lastSubmission = null;
            if (Request.Cookies["LastSubmission"] != null)
                lastSubmission = Convert.ToDateTime(Request.Cookies["LastSubmission"].Value);
            if (lastSubmission.HasValue && DateTime.Now < lastSubmission.Value.AddMinutes(5))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty,
                    "ERROR: Your application has not been sent. This is due to receiving an application from you within the last five minutes. If you have made an error and wish to resend your application, please wait five minutes and then complete the application again.");
                return View(model);
            }

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Something went wrong!");
                return View(model);
            }

            #endregion
}
```

P.S: model.Files is `IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase>`

Last but not least, when user click submit button, you should indicate some kind of loading screen or disable button to submit again. So user can understand something happening on the website...

And here is the javascript example for the validation.

```
function sendForm() {

    if (grecaptcha.getResponse() === "") {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#robotErrorDiv").slideDown();
        return false;
    } else {
        $("#robotErrorDiv").slideUp();
    }

    $("#myForm").validate();
    if ($("#myForm").valid()) {
        $("#loaderGif").fadeIn();
        $("#submitButton").text("Sending...").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        $("#myForm").submit();
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a variable in HTML5  local storage and verify it every time user clicks the button.

HTML 5 Local stores data for indefinite time even browser is closed  and reopened .
But if user clears local storage than he can submit again. But at least it will reduce number of hits from same user .

For more about HTMl5 local storage refer 
https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp